# Extension php_win32service installs the service, but the service won't start up (hangs)

Tags: php, windows, windows-services

I am trying to setup a PHP web application on a Windows Server 2008 SP1 machine. We have this application running correctly on a Windows Server 2003, but are now unable to get the Windows services built with php_win32service `PHP` extension starting up correctly.

Here are the relevant sections of the `PHP` code. Here is the section that does the install and uninstall:

```
if ($argv[1] == 'install') {
    win32_create_service(array(
        'service' => $service_name,
        'display' => $service_name,
        'params' => '"'. __FILE__ . '"' . ' run'));
        exit;
} 
else if ($argv[1] == 'uninstall') {
    win32_delete_service($service_name);
    exit;
} 
else if ($argv[1] != 'run') {
   die("Invalid arguments");
}

win32_start_service_ctrl_dispatcher($service_name);
```

And here is the main loop:

```
while (1) {
    switch (win32_get_last_control_message()) {
       case WIN32_SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE: win32_set_service_status(WIN32_SERVICE_RUNNING); break; // Respond with status
       case WIN32_SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP: win32_set_service_status(WIN32_SERVICE_STOPPED);  exit; // Terminate script
    }         
    processQueue();
    usleep(500000);
}
```

The install and uninstall work as long as I run `cmd` as administrator. If I launch `cmd` under the account that I use to login to the server then the service is not created `win32_create_service`. I can also run the script with the `run` parameter from the command line and it runs correctly, but when I try start the service it just hangs on with the `Starting` message and never goes into `Started` state.

I think this issue has something to do with the rights of the `LocalSystem` account on the machine, but I do not know what rights are needed to get this to work properly. I also do not know how I can debug this and find out what error/issue is occurring with the `WIN32_SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE`, especially as I do not have rights on this server to make changes to security settings. Any changes that I need made to security settings I need to communicate to the network administrator so that he can perform the changes. Can anyone offer any help with debugging or resolving this issue?

UPDATE:

This issue only seems to occur in the 64-bit version of `PHP`. It seems that the 64-bit compile of `php_win32service` runs into some sort of problem when trying to start the service. I removed the 64-bit versions of `PHP` and 'php_win32service' and replaced them with the 32-bit versions. The service then started correctly.

Comment: Have you tried with NetworkService account? Other way is creating own service account. Do you communicate outside the server? Maybe firewall?

Comment: Hi eL-Prova. Thanks for your reply. No we are not communicating with an outside server. I will try the NetworkService account and will give feedback here when I have tested this. Thanks.

Comment: If that will be the answer, i will post it as anwer so you can mark it:)

Comment: I am waiting to get hold of the network administrator for the password for this account, that is why I can't test it yet. But, yep, if it solves the problem then post an answer and I will mark it! :)

Comment: @eL-Prova Unfortunately I cannot confirm or deny whether the change you proposed would make a difference, because the company I was setting the software up for refused to give me the password to the NetworkService account. But put your comment as an answer and I will mark it up. I did find a work-around to this issue though. I will give details on this in an update to the question. Thanks for your help on this issue.

Comment: I posted my answer :) To bad I cant help you as expected. However, next time I will try harder :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated Answer:

I am now convinced that this issue arises when you update or downgrade `PHP` to a different version, but fail to remove and recreate the services using the `php_win32service` for the newly installed version of `PHP`. This was mentioned as an aside in my old answer, but after encountering the same thing on another server and resolving it by removing and recreating the service entries, I am convinced that this is the true cause of this issue and that is not a bug in `PHP`.

Old Answer:

I encountered this issue again when I tried to update `PHP` on a `Windows Server 2008` machine from `5.3` to `5.6`. From the testing that I have done I have concluded that `php_win32service.dll` extension works correctly for `PHP 5.3`, but not from `5.4` upwards. From `5.4` there seems to be a bug whereby the function `win32_get_last_control_message` always returns 0 rather than a valid status.

I finally got a clue to what was going on from a post made over here:
http://enlinea.creaelicita.cl/guia/function.win32-set-service-status.html

So, if you have code such as this:

```
while (1) {
    switch (win32_get_last_control_message()) {
        case WIN32_SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE: win32_set_service_status(WIN32_SERVICE_RUNNING); break; // Respond with status
        case WIN32_SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP: win32_set_service_status(WIN32_SERVICE_STOPPED); exit; // Terminate script
    }    
    usleep(3000000);

    // Main script goes here
    processQueue();
}
```

then

```
win32_set_service_status(WIN32_SERVICE_RUNNING);
```

will never get called, because `win32_get_last_control_message` never gets the value of 4 (WIN32_SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE).

A workaround which I use is to add a default case to the switch statement that sets the service status. Like this:

```
 switch (win32_get_last_control_message()) {
        case WIN32_SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE: win32_set_service_status(WIN32_SERVICE_RUNNING); break; // Respond with status
        case WIN32_SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP: win32_set_service_status(WIN32_SERVICE_STOPPED); exit; // Terminate script
        default: win32_set_service_status(WIN32_SERVICE_RUNNING);
 }
```

As an aside, I also found that this issue occurred if I upgraded to `PHP 5.4` and did not recreate the service entries before trying to start them. So besides applying the above workaround, remember to first uninstall the windows service in question and reinstall it from your `PHP` script.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with NetworkService account? Other way is creating own service account. Do you communicate outside the server? Maybe firewall?

Ps. the network service account has a default password (system known)

***Note that this account does not have a password, so any password information that you provide in this call is ignored.***

http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx